# multipath propagation

Tags: audio, multipath

i recorded a tone between two  devices and applied cross correlation on the recorded and the sent signals. 
I want to know if there is a multipath effect on my result (on MATLAB). what can i use for that?

Comment: What do you mean by *tone*? Harmonic signal? If it is you can't see any multipath effect. You have to know your channel coherence bandwidth (at least roughly). If you choose waveform with good correlation properties and make a signal with bandwidth more than channel coherence bandwidth (e.g. 4-16 times), you can measure multipath effect via cross correlation of the signal received and reference one.

Comment: a linear chirp with 17-19KHz frequencies. what do you mean by correlation properties?

Comment: i read about Rayleigh distribution, but i did not know how to apply that.

Comment: By correlation properties I mean autocorrelation function. It should be narrow to estimate multipath. LFM seems good enough. Your signal bandwidth is 2 kHz. With this one you can detect multipath, if channel coherence bandwidth is about 1 kHz or less. Coherence bandwidth depends on two major factors: carrier frequency and environment. Find out what range of coherence bandwidth is possible for your task, and it will be clear whether you can detect multipath effect or not.

Comment: im sorry for my many questions but im not very familiar with signal processing (beginner), i found that coherence bandwidth can be calculated as 2PI/D, as D is the delay spread. how can i measure the delay spread?

Comment: Delay spread is the maximum delay between arrival of rows of significant power. *Significant* means here that the row power relate to main row power as no less than -20 dB for example. It is also effective length of channel impulse response if the channel is stationary. Alternatively delay spread can be extracted from the power delay profile (PDP) of the channel if it is available. PDP is provided sometimes by assumed channel model or by field tests. In your case I suppose some channel model with some known parameters is in use, isn't it?

Comment: i had to google that to understand channel model. No i have not done any.i just wanted to check the recorded chirp 's robustness against noise and multipath.

Comment: autocorrelation  looks like this [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MfUzf.png